# Adding Subsurface Modifier to Cylinder Not Smooth

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to get a nice rounded end to a cylinder. When I add a subsurface modifier plus an edge loop, the edge looks 'choppy':

[image]

Is there a way I can get this smooth? I've done this previously, but this was by adding a sphere at the ends. It would be nice to not have to add extra objects if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, topo.  More than one solution:

[image]

Left is unchanged.  Middle has control loops for the outside and the cap (your pic is missing the control loops for the cap) which can be made with 1 loop cut (ctrl r) and 1 face inset (i).  Rightmost has edges marked as sharp (ctrl e menu) and creased (shift e) for subsurf.